# Call Method inside a Method Unit testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mockito, android-testing

I got a presenter to be tested. Presenter contains a method which calls another method on some success return. Now how do I check whether that success return calls that method or not?

Here is the sample code, it simply verifies if a method of non mock object
`tutorProfileDataReceived(tutorProfiledata)` is the method I need to ensure to be called `onResponse`.

Now this gives Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

```
Call call = apiInterface.getTutorProfile(tutorProfile);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
                TutorProfile tutorProfiledata = (TutorProfile) response.body();
                tutorProfileDataReceived(tutorProfiledata);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG,"getting suggestions call cancel");
                call.cancel();
            }
        });
```

Testing work...

```
@Before
    public void setUp(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        apiInterface = NetworkContext.getInstance().getService(APIInterface.class);
        presenter = Mockito.spy(new TutorProfilePresenter(viewMock , contextMock));

    }

    @Test

        public void getTutorDataTest(){
            int searchId = 2;

            TutorProfile profileSender = new TutorProfile(searchId);
            Call<TutorProfile> call = apiInterface.getTutorProfile(profileSender);

            try {
                Response<TutorProfile> response = call.execute();
                TutorProfile profileReceiver = response.body();

                Mockito.verify(presenter).tutorProfileDataReceived(profileReceiver);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```